# what a keyboard shortcut which Go to begin and end of word in sublime text 3

Tags: css, html5-canvas, sublimetext3

My problem may a tiny problem of other however I try to google this but not find such a solution.

I'd like to  edit  text  within  'double quote , single quote' .
for example  if I have a long class name such as .

```
    <div class = "this_is_my_very_long_class_name" ></div>
```

What's a keyboard shortcus if I'd like to go to begin or end of a class name within a double quote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Ctrl + Left Arrow** and **Ctrl + Right arrow** to toggle between the beggining and the end of the word (Windows). In MAC OSX, I believe it is **Option + Left/Right arrow**.

Comment: Note that this does not apply only to ST; it can be used mostly anywhere where text can be edited.

Comment: BTW AFAICT Windows 10 [today*] does not have a standard keyboard shortcut to move to the end of the current word. It has a shortcut to move to the beginning of the next word. This makes a difference when you are writing keyboard macros for accessibility. // ^{Right}=>start of next word; ^{Left}=start of this word, or previous if already at start of current word. Shifting these extends selection. // Note *: Windows may have changed its standard keyboard shortcuts since OP. I am currently on Windows 10. – 
Krazy Glew